# Polygonize function doesn't overlay the shapefile over the raster file

Tags: qgis, polygonize

To convert the raster into a shapefile I use raster->conversion->polygonize but QGIS doesn't open the new layer overlayed the first (the raster) but reflected above it.

[image: below the original raster layer above it the reflected output]

I read this question [Polygonize problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28704/polygonize-problem) but it is incomplete and there are no solutions. I've changed CRS I used EPSG:4326 for both or User Defined but nothing...

I've changed image format, .tiff .jpg, nothing!

This is the original .bmp file:[image: original .bmp file]

These are the metadata of the shapefile:

`General:
Storage type of this layer: ESRI Shapefile
Source for this layer: gisprovavector
Geometry type of the features in this layer: Polygon
The number of features in this layer: 2
Editing capabilities of this layer: Add Features, Delete Features, Change Attribute Values, Add Attributes, Delete Attributes, Create Spatial Index, Fast Access to Features at ID, Change Geometries
Extents:
In layer spatial reference system units : xMin,yMin 0,0 : xMax,yMax 962,500
Layer Spatial Reference System:
+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS72 +towgs84=0,0,1.9,0,0,0.814,-0.38 +no_defs`

I use QGIS 1.8.0 in Windows XP!

Comment: Does this question provide any clues?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4801

Comment: I second @whuber's suggestion to check the prior question.  To directly address your problem, we need more information.  It would help to know the file format of your raster, the projection of the raster, and the projection that your shapefile is going to be.  It would be most helpful if you would edit your question and include the contents of the world file for your raster, and potentially before and after screenshots of your data.

Comment: @ underdark [marked as duplicate] I read this question Polygonize problem but it is incomplete and there were no solutions until I posted one. This is why I posted this question I tried to be more clear and put more information and images as request from previous users.I've no more things to add so I will not edit it if you think is a duplicate delete it. Thanks for your help! Best regards!

Comment: You're right, this question contains more information. The answer stays same. I turned it around and closed the older one now. Thanks for posting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the same thing happened to me I tried to use the polygonize algorithm in Windows and Linux with QGIS 1.7 and 1.8. Probably there is a little bug in GdalTools that inverts some values in the output file and so the output is reflected "mirror like". However I resolved it georeferencing the raster image BEFORE using the polygonize tool. Raster -> Georeferencer ->Georeferencer. This for the moment is the only solution I've found!